# JSON Not a standard nesting level

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, deserialization

If you simplify, you get the following JSON implementation:

> Data(Entity)->"data"->another Entity

I assumed that I would first decrypt the Data object, take a type from it, and from that type make a decryption with the necessary type from String "data", but my idea failed. Any ideas how to fix this?

I created a normal entity of this type

```
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty
    private String data;
}
```

In the "data" field I place an object, also converted by

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```

When trying to decrypt Data (not String "data") with

```
objectMapper.readValue(json, classz);
```

I get an error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Do you by any chance have some non-default constructor in your class? If so then also add no-arguments constructor. The error suggests that your class could not be instantiated. ANd that may occur if you have a non-default constructor that does not include all your properties and doesn't have no-arguments constructor. In this case Json lib wouldn't know how to instantiate your class

Comment: I did this of course, cut them out to make the code clearer